# How do I get my function to return something other than a reference?

Tags: python-3.x, function

When I run this function it returns `None` and a reference instead of the intended value.

I already am using "`return`" which is supposed to make the function return the intended value, but like I said it is still returning a reference.

```
def querydate():
    querydate = int(input("Please enter a year between 2000 and 2017 for 
    processing injury data "))

    numberchoice0 = querydate
    while numberchoice0 is querydate:
        try:
            while int(numberchoice0)<2000:
                print("oopsie, that year is before those for which this 
                       query searches.")
                quit()
            while int(numberchoice0)>2017:
                print("oopsie, that year is after those for which this 
                       query searches.")
                quit()
        except ValueError:
            print ('That was not an integer!')
            affirmations = ('YES', 'Y')
            answer = input("Do you want to continue? (Yes/Y/y):\n")
            if answer.strip().upper() in affirmations:
                continue
        else:
            return querydate()

print(querydate())

def verify():
    verify = input("please enter 'yes' or 'no' ")
    if verify == "no":
        print("You should be more careful about inputting data!")
        quit()
    while verify != "yes":
        print(verify, "is not an appropriate input. If you answered 'YES' 
              or 'Yes' please enter 'yes'")
        continue
    if verify == "yes":
        print("Great! Let us continue")

verify()
```

I expect the output to be a number between 2000 and 2017, but when I print `querydate()` it returns "`None`", and when I reference `querydate()` with `verify()` it actually returns `<function querydate at 0x000001F1DCFB9A60>`

Comment: Which value is the method suppose to return?

Comment: Why would the return value be a number? `return` in `querydate` is a shortcut for `return None`. Also, if a function doesn't explicitly return anything, `None` is returned automatically.

Comment: I apologize, I am editing the code, but my question still stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` does not make the function *return the intended value*, one has to explicitly specify it according to what one **wants** to return.

You wanted the output from `2000` to `2017` so you need to return the value that returns this.

```
def querydate():
    qDate = int(input("Please enter a year between 2000 and 2017 for 
    processing injury data "))

    numberchoice0 = qDate
    while numberchoice0 is qDate:
        try:
            while int(numberchoice0)<2000:
                print("oopsie, that year is before those for which this 
                       query searches.")
                quit()
            while int(numberchoice0)>2017:
                print("oopsie, that year is after those for which this 
                       query searches.")
                quit()
        except ValueError:
            print ('That was not an integer!')
            affirmations = ('YES', 'Y')
            answer = input("Do you want to continue? (Yes/Y/y):\n")
            if answer.strip().upper() in affirmations:
                continue
        else:
            return qDate #returning the integer instead of None

print(querydate())

def verify():
    verify = input("please enter 'yes' or 'no' ")
    if verify == "no":
        print("You should be more careful about inputting data!")
        quit()
    while verify != "yes":
        print(verify, "is not an appropriate input. If you answered 'YES' 
              or 'Yes' please enter 'yes'")
        continue
    if verify == "yes":
        print("Great! Let us continue")

verify()
```

Also since you had returned explicitly nothing, referencing `querydate()` with `verify()` should return *the address reference* but if you had returned an integer like  `querydate` or `numberchoice0` then it returns a year from range `2000-2017`.

Edit:

As far as your `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`  is concerned, it happens due to the naming of *local variable* and *function name* being same. So at first the identifier `querydate`  refers to the **function** `querydate()` then it goes inside the function and now it refers to a **variable** `querydate` and no longer refers to the **function** when assigning of var `querydate` is encountered. So changing the name of one of the identifiers fixes the issue.

Comment: I added return querydate to my code and am still returning the address reference.  I also tried adding return querydate() which made the answer an integer, but the integer is uncallable: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable     
PS where can I learn to highlight words like you did?

Comment: Updated my answer @HezekiahBodine

Comment: Yes @faruk13 my issue is fully resolved now. Thanks a lot!